Hurl tool - Output option cli flag not generating file when run a Hurl script
I want to use Hurl tool to chain some API calls: 
the output of request #1 to be input for request #2 and so on. 
The output of every Hurl script running has to be persisted as a file (project requirement). 
I spined up a Hurl docker container to test the output Hurl feature – the container has a volume mapped to a local Hurl files scripts:
docker run -d \
    --name hurl-debug-001 \
    -v "D:\local\hurl-files:/hurl-files" \
    --entrypoint sleep ghcr.io/orange-opensource/hurl:latest infinity

The container is kept alive and Hurl script files are available:

The /hurl-files/request-001.hurl Hurl file has the following content:
GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

If I run the following command by following output flag:
hurl \
    --test --color --insecure \
    --output /hurl-files/result.json \
    /hurl-files/request-001.hurl

... then the script is working fine:

but no /hurl-files/result.json has been generated in hurl-files folder. 
If I run the following command:
hurl \
    --test --color --insecure \
    /hurl-files/request-001.hurl > /hurl-files/result.json

... then an empty /hurl-files/result.json is generated. \
The only working way seems to be the hard-coding of the output file in /hurl-files/request-001.hurl file as an output:
GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
[Options]
output: output/001.txt

The  output/001.txt is generated:

... with this content:

This last option which is working (output file hard-coded in Hurl script) is not a convenient one for my project – needs to be dynamic and set outside of the script.
Could you please guide me to find a solution to save the output of a Hurl script into a file by using some options/flag Hurl cli?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the screen shots of command output with plain text?  Do you have trouble with any specific code here; what you've shown so far looks like you're using a CLI tool to fetch URLs?  What benefits are you hoping to get from running it in a container?

maintainer of Hurl here.
It sounds like a bug with the CLI, not related with Docker! Usually with --test, there is no response output on stdout. With --output response output should be outputted. You have some workaround:

don't use --test: Hurl will still do assertions, you will miss the summary at the end of test but you'll have access to the response output with --output
if you do want to use --test you can use --report-json: it's a report where every part of the response is dumped (headers, body etc...)

In the mean time, you can make an issue on the GitHub repo I'll fix it asap.

Hello @jcamiel - indeed removing --test did the trick.
I will raise an issue. Thanks for your support!

Hello @jcamiel - I created the issue
